# Join not working as expected (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, identity

I can't for the life of me figure out how to join these two tables on UserName using entity framework.

I tried both the statement and the method and neither worked.

The tables definitely have the same user in them

```
var employees = _context.Employees.Include(e => e.Loc);

//Only show employees with a user role of manager
var managerUsers = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Manager");

var match = (from e in employees
                     join m in managerUsers on e.UserName equals m.UserName
                     select new { Employee = e }).ToList();
```

So, short code breakdown I get a list of all employees from the database context. I look in user roles to find a list of users with the Manager role. Employee also has a UserName field, and I tried to join them using the UserName field. There is one manager currently returning correctly in both tables with a matching username, yet after this code, match has 0 results.

I also tried it like this:

```
employees.Join(managerUsers,
               e => e.UserName,
               m => m.UserName,
               (e,m) => new { e }).ToList();
```

But that also doesn't return any records. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried `join m in managerUsers on e.UserName.ToLower() equals m.UserName.ToLower()`?

Comment: var match = from p in employees
                                    where managerUsers.Contains(p.UserName)
                                    select new Employee
                                    {
                                        Id = p.Id,
                                        //etc etc
                                    };  -- You will need to do a select on your managerUsers so it is only bringing back UserName.

Comment: Also note that joining on to a non queryable will result in EF not being able to translate the expression to SQL. As you are using a repository to join on to, It is unclear what this type is. If the repository is not a deferred query then you need to make sure that the data you want to join on to is already in memory as the expression evaluate will evaluate this in memory not on the SQL sever.

Comment: Why not use navigation properties to define the relationship between the entities?  That way you don't need to join explicitly and could do something like `_context.Employees.Include(e => e.Loc).Where(e=>e.Roles.Any(r=>r.RoleName == "Manager"));`  obviously this assumes you are in a position to change the entities so if that's not an option then this is not good for you.. (or if you go the other way and a role has its users defined via nav properties: `users = _context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.RoleName=="Manager")?.Users` which is clearer IMO

Comment: Razvan, both usernames are already all caps, so that wouldn't make a difference 
Kingtreelo, managerUsers.Contains(p.UserName) gives an error cannot convert from string to ApplicationUser

Comment: GPW - Employee does not contain a list of Roles. the roles comes from entity framework UserManager. Are you saying i should somehow add roles as a property of Employee?

Comment: Kieran, Can you explain more? Employee is of type IQueryable, but managerUsers is not. Can i convert a list to iqueryable? This might be the key here I'll look in to it

Comment: I tried var queryable = managerUsers.AsQueryable(); and then join m in queryable on e.UserName equals m.UserName but it's still getting 0 results, but i could be doing it wrong

Comment: I figured it out. Not the most elegant solution because i had to loop, but :
var managerEmployees = new List<Employee>();

                for(int a = 0; a< selectManagersList.Count(); a++)
                {
                    var found = await _context.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u=> u.UserName == managerUsers.ElementAt(a).UserName);
                    if (found!=null)
                    {
                        managerEmployees.Add(found);
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution myself

```
        var managerEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        for(int a = 0; a< selectManagersList.Count(); a++)
        {
            var found = await _context.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u=> u.UserName == managerUsers.ElementAt(a).UserName);
            if (found!=null)
            {
                managerEmployees.Add(found);
            }
        }
```